# How to use tokens in frontend for authentication

Tags: python, django, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I am currently developing a React-Django app and using dj-rest-auth package and JWT for authentication on the backend. It works perfectly fine and when a user loggs in, server responses with a HttpOnly cookie which contains access_token.

What I don't understand is how can I use the access_token that in the response-cookie for requests in my web app if I can't read the token value from my frontend since it is HttpOnly?

I tried js-cookie package for storing JWT in cookies and since it is written in JS, I can't make it HttpOnly. So I am storing access_token in a cookie but doesn't it break the point of HttpOnly cookies since they both store the same token value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send the token to your api call on the headers as `Authorization Bearer + token`